Wrap create function in a do statement
I have a create function statement, that I'd like to wrap around a DO statement to check if the function exists. However, I'm having a bit of trouble with the syntax. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Function, works:
CREATE FUNCTION write_pos_history()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE ...
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Wrap attempt, error: unexpected end of function definition at end of input
DO $$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_proc
               WHERE proname = 'write_pos_history'
               AND pg_function_is_visible(oid)) THEN
      CREATE FUNCTION write_pos_history()
      RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE ...
         RETURN NEW;
      END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   END IF;
END $$;


What do you think the $$ sequences mean?

Have you considered CREATE OR REPLACE ... ?

Dollar-quoting basics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

@Lennart-SlavaUkraini CREATE OR REPLACE has concurrency issues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525684/tuple-concurrently-updated-when-creating-functions-in-postgresql-pl-pgsql), which is actually my original problem

The documentation will tell you about “dollar quoting”.
If you need to nest dollar quoted strings, you need different delimiters; for example:
DO
$$...
   CREATE FUNCTION ... AS $fun$...$fun$;
...$$;

